# Tweening opacity in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I am having a weird issue with tweening the opacity of a mesh in threejs.  It only seems to work when I move my camera while the tween happens.  I thought maybe someone might have come across this issue.

This is the code I use to tween my mesh:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mesh.material.materials.length; i++) {
    new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.material.materials[i]).to({ opacity: .6 }, 700).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out).start();
}
```

I don't really thing it is the tweening code.. I think I need to ask threejs to re-render somehow?  It is as if three js doesn't want to do any tweening unless the camera is moving.

If it helps, I am using `WebGLRenderer`, `TrackballControls`, and `PerspectiveCamera`.

Comment: Do you call `TWEEN.update();` in your animation loop?

Comment: I just looked and I do have that line in there.

Comment: Do other tweens work (e.g. changing the position of the mesh)? I agree that the tweening code looks good.

Comment: So, I ended up being able to fix it by including `.onUpdate(render)` to my tween.

Comment: Did you set all materials to **transparent = true**; ? because the default is false and it will remain opaque. [Material Docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material)